# finding date intervals start and end dates

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this (plus 10 more columns) containing more than 1 million of frequently updated records:

```
 id pid start_date          end_date  
  1 761 2011-07-25 00:00:00 2011-08-01 00:00:00
  2 761 2011-08-01 00:00:00 2011-08-22 00:00:00
  3 761 2011-08-22 00:00:00 2011-09-19 00:00:00
  4 802 2011-08-22 00:00:00 2011-09-19 00:00:00
  5 761 2011-06-05 00:00:00 2011-07-05 00:00:00
```

and would like to get result for a particular pid (761 in the example below) with all consecutive intervals combined:

```
 id pid start_date          end_date  
  1 761 2011-07-25 00:00:00 2011-09-19 00:00:00
  5 761 2011-06-05 00:00:00 2011-07-05 00:00:00
```

Currently I am doing this in the code, but would like to move this functionality entirely to the db side.
Any ideas how to do this?

edit: start_date and end_date columns are of DATETIME type.

Comment: Do you have the `pid` value at the time you will run the query?

Comment: @Shef - yes, I do have the pid value when running the query.

Comment: Are `start_date` and `end_date` columns `DATETIME` type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really much better done in code.  Loop over the rows, when it's for the same product, update the end date, otherwise create a new array entry.

For an idea of how complex this is in SQL, see m[y attempt at solving this in SQL Server](http://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/76185/puzzling-query-to-join-up-events?page=1#76187) :)

Comment: It does look complex from a performance pov. Also i am not sure how easily can it be ported to mysql, but it did gave me a number of hints. Thanks!